# SHOW COLUMNS syntax Issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to find Show Columns like and referring to this :
[sql show columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-columns.html)

But something wrong with Syntax:

```
SHOW COLUMNS  LIKE '%ACCOUNT_ID%'   IN { ACCOUNT | [ DATABASE ] "CLIENT_DB" | [ SCHEMA ] "ACCOUNTS" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the statements below:

```
SHOW COLUMNS LIKE '%ACCOUNT_ID%' IN DATABASE CLIENT_DB;

SHOW COLUMNS LIKE  '%ACCOUNT_ID%' IN SCHEMA CLIENT_DB.ACCOUNTS;
```